# Side effects and I/O in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Ok so I'm a newbie to Haskell IO. I've read a lot about IO and side effects in Haskell functions, and now I have come to do some side effects of my own in Haskell and I'm wondering - how do I actually write this stuff?

I have the following function, whereupon after running one of the lines of code, I want to do some printing, which is explained by the comments in the first couple of lines.

I'm pretty sure I need to change the function's type signature, maybe I'll need to use Maybe. Maybe it's not even possible to do this way and I have to completely rewrite it? I don't really know - but I'm looking for guidance. How do I go about including this functionality?

```
interpret_statement :: Prog -> Vars -> Stmt -> Vars -- one third of the debug -d functionality goes here 
                                                    -- AFTER every assignment is executed, the interpreter should print a line specifying
                                                    -- the variable being assigned to AND its new value
interpret_statement prog vars@(Vars _ b c d) (Assign A expr) = Vars (interpret_expr prog vars expr) b c d
interpret_statement prog vars@(Vars a _ c d) (Assign B expr) = Vars a (interpret_expr prog vars expr) c d
interpret_statement prog vars@(Vars a b _ d) (Assign C expr) = Vars a b (interpret_expr prog vars expr) d
interpret_statement prog vars@(Vars a b c _) (Assign D expr) = Vars a b c (interpret_expr prog vars expr)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to start with the code from Adrian's answer.

```
interpret_statement :: Prog -> Vars -> Stmt -> IO Vars
interpret_statement prog vars@(Vars _ b c d) (Assign A expr) = do
    print "some debug"
    return $ Vars (interpret_expr prog vars expr) b c d
-- etc
```

This is correct as far as it goes, but there are some issues:

- the debugging output is compulsory, but presumably you want it to be optional
- although we need the result type to be `IO Vars` in order to perform i/o, this makes it harder to test `interpret_statement`

A solution:

- add a function parameter to `interpret_statement` that performs any required i/o
- make that function polymorphic so that its result type determines the result type of `interpret_statement`

e.g. (and forgive me for guessing at your types: I assume `data VarName = A | B | C | D` and `data Vars = Vars Value Value Value Value`):

```
interpret_statement :: (VarName -> Value -> Vars -> o) ->
                       Prog -> Vars -> Stmt -> o
interpret_statement debug prog vars@(Vars _ b c d) (Assign A expr)
    = debug A newValue $ Vars (interpret_expr prog vars expr) b c d
-- etc
```

Useful functions you can provide as that parameter are:

```
purePassthrough :: VarName -> Value -> Vars -> Vars
purePassthrough _ _ vars = vars
```

- use when you are testing `interpret_statement` from QuickCheck
  and would like it to be pure
- `interpret_statement purePassthrough :: Prog -> Vars -> Stmt -> Vars`,
  as in your original `interpret_statement`

```
writeDebuggingInfo :: VarName -> Value -> Vars -> IO Vars
writeDebuggingInfo varName newValue newVars = do
    putStrLn $ show varName ++ " := " ++ show newValue
        -- or whatever debugging output you want
    return newVars
```

- use in your program when you require debugging information to be written
- `interpret_statement writeDebuggingInfo :: Prog -> Vars -> Stmt -> IO Vars`,
  as in Adrian's answer

```
dontWriteDebuggingInfo :: VarName -> Value -> Vars -> IO Vars
dontWriteDebuggingInfo :: _ _ newVars = return newVars
```

- `interpret_statement dontWriteDebuggingInfo :: Prog -> Vars -> Stmt -> IO Vars`,
  as in the previous case
- use when you may or may not want debugging output, e.g.

  ```
  newVars <- interpret_statement (if wantDebuggingOutput then writeDebuggingInfo
                                                    else dontWriteDebuggingInfo)
                 program vars statement
  ```

Comment: wow ok so this is just as complicated as I thought it would be. I'm glad I asked a question about it. I think I need to mention this in case it complicates things - the code itself that I supplied does no debugging, but my final product will have a parameter PASSED in called debug, or something like that, and based on the value of that parameter, it does this IO or not. May not complicate things.... but I wouldn't be surprised if I did. Sorry for not mentioning that earlier. I'm just getting to work on actually trying out your suggestion

Comment: Ok I was really hoping it would not be this complicated, which is why I did not mention that there are several co-dependent functions that make this interpreter work. I thought it would be possible to localise the IO to interpret_statement, but it seems this is causing problems because it is returning polymorphic type "o" to other functions such as interpret_expr and interpret_stmt_list, which have in the past taken in "Vals" but now may need to take in "o". This is also affecting things when I write vars@(Vars a b c d), it needs a polymorphic type? Really no idea what to do.

Comment: Ran out of space in the last comment - sorry but I am really bamboozled by this! What information do I need to show? Perhaps the entire program?

Comment: ACTUALLY, I have done some fiddling, and all Haskell is complaining about for now is that when I call pure_passthrough [e.g. interpret_statement prog debug_function (interpret_stmt_list prog debug_function vars stmt_list) (While expr stmt_list)], the expected type is Var -> Val -> Vars -> Vars, but it actually gets Var -> Val -> Vars -> o. How is that remedied?

Comment: Hey I'm going to select your answer and open a new question since you did answer a lot of my questions. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

You are correct. If you want to do some printing your code must live in some monad. Monad responsible for handling operations on real world - like printing on screen - is IO monad. So to use functions like `putStrLn, print, getLine` you need to change function signature to:

```
interpret_statement :: Prog -> Vars -> Stmt -> IO Vars
```

And use `do` notation. Result of the function must be then wrapped by `return` funciton, but I am sure you already know this about monads.

For example:

```
interpret_statement prog vars@(Vars _ b c d) (Assign A expr) = do
    print "some debug"
    return $ Vars (interpret_expr prog vars expr) b c d
```